# Olingo Configuration for Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, odata

According to this page https://www.baeldung.com/olingo you can make the registration resource like this:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/odata")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig(CarsODataJPAServiceFactory serviceFactory, EntityManagerFactory emf) {        
        ODataApplication app = new ODataApplication();        
        app
          .getClasses()
          .forEach( c -> {
              if ( !ODataRootLocator.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                  register(c);
              }
          });
         
        register(new CarsRootLocator(serviceFactory)); 
        register(new EntityManagerFilter(emf));
    }
     
    // ... other methods omitted
}
```

The thing is, i made some investigation in public github repositories and the code above is for glassfish servers.

I need to deploy a SpringBoot Application with Odata, but there is no documentation at sight about how to replicate this configuration for tomcat servers.